# Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

**what the console prints**, I am trying to run a java web application on netbeans and I do not understand very well why it gives me that error.

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.4/xstream-1.4.4.jar (483 kB at 33 kB/s)
Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalProvisionException.toProvisionException (InternalProvisionException.java:226)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$1.get (InjectorImpl.java:1053)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance (InjectorImpl.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get (AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision (ProviderInternalFactory.java:85)
```

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war (default-war) on project primera_web: Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3:war failed: Unable to load the mojo 'war' in the plugin 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3' due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: null

```
realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/HP/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.3/maven-war-plugin-2.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/HP/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/HP/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/HP/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar

Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
: ExceptionInInitializerError: Unable to make field private final java.util.Comparator java.util.TreeMap.comparator accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @5c82031b
-> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

**file pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>primera_web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>primera_web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

suggestions to solve the problem ??

Comment: try deleting full .m2/repository and try again

Comment: Update all plugin version you are using... See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: @khmarbaise The link is not really explaining how to do that. Please make a proper answer and not just an comment.

Answer (score 92):

I had the same problem. I am using Eclipse Jun 2021 release. The problem got resolved after manually configuring one of the recent war plug-ins in POM.xml.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: FYI, [current version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-war-plugin) is 3.3.2.

Comment: it worked for me .
earlier i was not having this plugin section but after adding it and updating maven, cleaning maven and installing it  it worked

Comment: Worked for me as well thank you sir

Comment: not working with 3.8.0

Answer (score 8):

I experienced the same issue after upgrading from JDK 1.8 to JDK 17 and I solved it by upgrading the plugin version.

Before:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</plugin>
```

After:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: this was actually the right answer for me

Answer (score 5):

My problem got resolved after manually configuring war plug-in in POM.xml and then do clean install

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Then in the terminal, do a clean install, as:

```
mvn clean install
```

This should give you the war file (javaj22ee.war) status like:

```
[INFO] Building war: /Users/my_proj/java/javaj2ee/target/javaj2ee.war
[INFO]
[INFO] --- install:3.1.1:install (default-install) @ javaj2ee ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/my_proj/java/javaj2ee/pom.xml to 
/Users/.m2/repository/org/example/javaj2ee/1.0-SNAPSHOT/javaj2ee-1.0- 
SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/my_proj/java/javaj2ee/target/javaj2ee.war to 
/Users/.m2/repository/org/example/javaj2ee/1.0-SNAPSHOT/javaj2ee-1.0- 
SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
[INFO] Total time:  8.506 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-04T18:37:31+05:30
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: fixing the version worked awesome :)
thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

if you want to deploy the war. what worked for me is both

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>16</source>
                <target>16</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Please note the versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by changing the JDK in your projects to JDK 14. Left-click on your project and go to properties -> build -> compile . Change the JDK to version 14. If you don't have JDK 14, you can manage it there by clicking Manage Java Platforms. The download of the JDK is [here](https://jdk.java.net/archive/).

Answer (score 1):

Your `pom.xml` like this will work.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>vysample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>vysample-1.0-SNAPSHOT</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>9.0.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Focus at

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this error by adding following part in pom.xml

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

apart from that i added maven configuration properties

```
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

and here is my entire file as following

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.groupId</groupId>
<artifactId>com.artifactId</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
    <dependency>
    
        <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0</version>

    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by simply going in the Jenkins global tool configuration and changing the path of JDK to `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.10`.
Previously it was `/usr/local/Cellar/openjdk/16.0.1` in my local machine MAC.

[Click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Gmm.png)

This was the error :

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar (431 kB at 529 kB/s)
11:52:49 [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo
11:52:49 com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
11:52:49 
11:52:49 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: Cannot access defaults field of Properties
11:52:49   at org.apache.maven.plugin.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 2021-06 release by default JDK will be set to 16. So changed to your preferred JDK version. or configure your default JDK to run
[image]

```
maven-war-plugin:3.0.0:war (default-war) @ projectname 
--- [WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugins.war.WarMojo 
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, 
see the following errors: 1) Error injecting constructor,
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError 
at org.apache.maven.plugins.war.WarMojo.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue.  After updating the POM file, I needed to delete my `.m2/repository` folder before running `mvn install` for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and I resolved changed the version 2.3 to 3.3.1

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.3.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7CBy.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81nhk.png)

Answer (score -1):

Problem has been resolved by stopping the Tomcat server
`sudo systemctl stop tomcat`
so as to allow Netbeans to run it. If the server is already running when Netbeans tries to deploy an app Netbeans will display the delopy failed message.